# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/medialib/codec/png/Decoder in Tomcat 8 server when trying to read PNG images with ImageIO.read

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, javax.imageio

In recent deployments in my Tomcat 8 server I am getting the following error when trying to read PNG images as InputStream with ImageIO.read() as shown below:

```
InputStream imageInput = storageResource.getData();
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(imageInput);
```

ERROR:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: codecLib error
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.decode(CLibPNGImageReader.java:78)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.clib.CLibImageReader.getImage(CLibImageReader.java:497)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.getImageTypes(CLibPNGImageReader.java:117)
        at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getRawImageType(ImageReader.java:681)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.clib.CLibImageReader.read(CLibImageReader.java:571)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
        at com.media.entra.publication.image.PlatformImageUrlHandler.getImageCreationDescriptor(PlatformImageUrlHandler.java:272)
        at com.media.entra.publication.image.PlatformImageUrlHandler.parseImageUrl(PlatformImageUrlHandler.java:208)
        at de.think.image.ImageProcessor.doBefore(ImageProcessor.java:80)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.ProcessorFilter.doFilterImpl(ProcessorFilter.java:74)
        at com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:206)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.LooseFilterChain$Chain.doFilter(LooseFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.ProcessorFilter.doFilterImpl(ProcessorFilter.java:76)
        at com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:206)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.LooseFilterChain$Chain.doFilter(LooseFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.ProcessorFilter.doFilterImpl(ProcessorFilter.java:76)
        at com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:206)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.LooseFilterChain$Chain.doFilter(LooseFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.LooseFilterChain.filter(LooseFilterChain.java:69)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.CompositeFilter.doFilterImpl(CompositeFilter.java:36)
        at com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.scened.presentation.servlet.BootstrapFilter.doFilterImpl(BootstrapFilter.java:81)
        at com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.GenericFilter.doFilter(GenericFilter.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:41)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/medialib/codec/png/Decoder
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.decode(CLibPNGImageReader.java:75)
        ... 44 more
```

The problem appears to be in this CLibPNGImageReader.java file which originates from the jai-imageio-core. I've check my lib folder and it seems I have this JAR (jai_imageio-1.1.jar & also jai_core-1.1.3.jar & jai_codec-1.1.3.jar).
I have to point out that I don't directly import the jai packages they probably are dependecies of javax.imageio.ImageIO.

Is there a way to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: Try using this system property `-Dcom.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib=true`

Comment: @Smile ok will add this in the catalina.properties. Will this have an impact in the process of reading the PNGs?

Comment: Problem still persists, the issue is resolved after repeated restarts of the tomcat service.